# String taut condition in a Vertical Circular Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, string

Suppose, a ball is tied to a massless string attached to fixed point. In the initial condition, it hangs freely along the vertical in the influence of gravity. Now it is given an initial velocity u in the right direction. The string completes more than a quarter but less then half of the circle and makes an angle θ with the upper vertical at which it follows a parabolic path. At what point of the path, will the string be taut again?

I want to know how to approach this question. I did make a diagram of it.

[image]